# Trying to freeze first 2 columns using primefaces freezeColumn getting javascript error

Tags: primefaces

I am not able to freeze the columns using primefaces .getting javascript error .is there a work around for this.

Comment: What PF version are you using?

Comment: Putting the error here is a good place to start